# ffmpeg with php exec disabled?

Tags: ffmpeg

The Gallery2 script uses SYSTEM() & EXEC() to call FFMPEG

For security reasons both those PHP functions appear to have been disabled on my shared web hosting server.

Is there another method to use for executing FFMPEG?

Comment: I doubt it, since it would be blocked for the same reason SYSTEM() and EXEC() are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Can you upload your own CGIs?  If so, upload a bash script (named something.cgi) that starts ffmpeg and visit it.

Try making a file called "foo.cgi" with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
ls -Fal
```

Upload that to your web root, then go to http://yoursite/foo.cgi

Comment: Sorry not understanding. This is a shared web server among 100 clients or so. None are granted ssh ability, but only ftp.

Comment: You could FTP a bash script (renamed to something.cgi) into your web root, then go to that page with a browser.  The bash script will run on the server, and you can run whatever you want that way.

For a start, try something like this:
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "Content-type: text/plain"
   echo ""
   ls

If you see a directory listing when you go to that cgi, you're good.

Comment: argh, markup.  I'll add the code I intended to my answer.